# Update setuptools on Docker

Tags: dockerfile, setuptools, python-3.8

I am trying to update setuptools on my Dockerfile in order to solve the vulnerability
[CVE-2022-40897](https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-RHEL6-PYTHONSETUPTOOLS-3226975).

However, when going to the Jfrog of the project, with neither of them appears the setuptools with a higher version than when neither of these options is followed.

I have tried the following options:

1. `RUN apk add --upgrade py3-setuptools`
2. `RUN apk upgrade --no-cache py3-setuptools`
3. `RUN python -m ensurepip RUN pip install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools`

Any ideas of how can I force setuptools to be updated on the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vulnerability is fixed in `setuptools` version 65.5.1. To specify the new version of `setuptools` in your Dockerfile, include the following:

`RUN pip install setuptools>=65.5.1`

Alternatively, if your project contains a "requirements.txt" file, then you can add the following line to that file:
`setuptools>=65.5.1`

Comment: I tried this but Trivy still complains about the CVE, and I can see that setuptools 58.1.0 is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`. I'm using `python:3.9-bullseye` as a base image.